# Upload PDF with Next.js api route

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, multipartform-data

I'm sending a PDF upload as part of a payload to an in-house tool that is separate from my Next.js application through an API route. I'm having trouble getting the `FileList` to upload correctly. It's part of a form built with `react-hook-form`, I'm appending the pdf to `formData`, and it's being correctly converted to a binary that submits to the API route. However, the API hangs and doesn't do anything. This is what my component looks like:

**OnboardingDetails.tsx**

```
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { Button, Input, Spinner } from '@vero/ui';
import { useOnboardingStep } from 'client-data/hooks/use-onboarding-step';
import { inferMutationInpu } from 'client-data/utils/trpc';
import { env } from 'env/client.mjs';
import { OnboardingPageProps } from 'pages/onboarding';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

type InputType = inferMutationInput<'users.onboarding-details'>;

export const OnboardingDetails = ({
  user,
}: {
  user: OnboardingPageProps['user'];
}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  useOnboardingStep();

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    watch,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<InputType>({
    defaultValues: {
      resume: null,
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = async (values: InputType) => {
    if (!values.resume) {
      toast.error(`Resume is required.`);
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('resume', values.resume);

    await fetch(`/api/upload-user`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3 className="m-0 p-0 text-3xl">What are your contact details?</h3>
      <form
        className="flex w-full flex-col gap-6"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      >
        <Controller
          name="resume"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={null}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Input
              showLabel
              label="Resume"
              type="file"
              onChange={(e) => {
                field.onChange(e.target.files);
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Button
          type="submit"
          className="btn-primary"
          disabled={isLoading}
          icon={isLoading && <Spinner />}
        >
          Next
        </Button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Like I said, when I submit the form I'm able to see the `pdf` that I upload converted to a binary, but I don't receive a response; this is what my API route looks like:

**upload-user.ts**

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

import { authOptions } from './auth/[...nextauth]';

import { getServerSession } from '@vero/lib/auth';
import { prisma } from '@vero/prisma';
import { uploadUser } from '@vero/rater';
import { env } from 'env/server.mjs';

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const body = req.body;

  const session = await getServerSession({ req, res }, authOptions);

  try {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
      res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method Not Allowed' });
      return;
    }

    if (!session) {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
      return;
    }

    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: session.user.id,
      },
      select: {
        id: true,
        name: true,
        email: true,
        recruit: {
          select: {
            github_username: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });

    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
      return;
    }

    await uploadUser({
      apiKey: env.RATER_API_KEY,
      baseUrl: env.RATER_API,
      userEmail: user.email as string,
      userName: user.name as string,
      usernameList: user?.recruit?.github_username as string,
      userId: user.id,
      runAll: true,
      resume: body.resume[0],
    });

    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error });
  }
};

export default handler;
```

And then, my `uploadUser` function:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';
import fs from 'fs';
import { z } from 'zod';

const UploadUserInput = z.object({
  apiKey: z.string(),
  baseUrl: z.string().url(),
  usernameList: z.string(),
  userEmail: z.string(),
  userName: z.string(),
  userId: z.string(),
  resume: z.any().optional(),
  runAll: z.boolean(),
});

const GetUsernameFromIdInput = z.object({
  accountId: z.string(),
});

export const getUsernameFromId = async (args: { accountId: string }) => {
  const { accountId } = GetUsernameFromIdInput.parse(args);

  const res = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/user/${accountId}`);

  const userData = await res.json();

  return userData.login;
};

export const uploadUser = async (args: {
  apiKey: string;
  baseUrl: string;
  usernameList: string;
  userEmail: string;
  userName: string;
  runAll: boolean;
  userId: string;
  resume?: File;
}) => {
  const {
    apiKey,
    baseUrl,
    usernameList,
    userEmail,
    userName,
    runAll,
    userId,
    resume,
  } = UploadUserInput.parse(args);

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('username_list', usernameList);
  data.append('user_email', userEmail);
  data.append('user_name', userName);
  data.append('school_user_id', userId);
  data.append('resume', resume);

  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `${baseUrl}/api/upload-user/?runAllScrapers=${runAll}`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: apiKey,
    },
    data: data,
  };

  return await axios(config);
};
```

To clarify, I need to be able to submit the PDF upload from the client to the server, then send the data to our external tool. I'm receiving the binary from the client, and am even able to log it in the `req.body`, but I can't do anything with it beyond that. It just makes the API route hang up.

Comment: As far as I understood, everything works up until this point: `return await axios(config)`. If so can you run this in try catch and try to console if any error